# Can I discover JMX interfaces?

Tags: java, jmx

I have a vendor JavaEE application. Its documentation has a single paragraph that says *"The product has a JMX interface where you can do X, Y and Z"*. There is no further doco.

How should I go about discovering (by hand or programmatically) what the interface URI is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could deploy a Jolokia Agent on the Java EE Server side-by-side of the Java EE app and then use jmx4perl's j4psh for exploring the JMX namespace. See http://vimeo.com/20215477 for a demo. Or you use `jmx4perl http://.... list | grep 'X'` for looking of MBean which do 'X'.

If you then have the MBean name and the Attribute and/or Operation name's you can use any standard JMX interfadce for accessing this information.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the machine where the J2EE app is deployed, then you could login there and check the port usage and see which ports are being used by what processes. You may be able to guess the port name where the JMX is registered. Once you find that, you may be able to go to the JMX console.

But there should be some other way to do it. Maybe if you can login to the Tomcat admin or JBOss admin, there should be some clues there. Additionaly, you can try using JConsole to connect to the server machine.